# How did physicists measure which slit the electron went through?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

In the double-slit experiment, when physicists measured which slit the electron passes through , the wave-like behavior broke and interference pattern disappeared.

How did the physicists observe/measure which slit the electrons went through?

What was the device they used to observe/measure?

Comment: This seems to depend on the specific experiment; there is likely more than onedevice that can be used to mark the passage through the slits.

Comment: @ACuriousMind could u name one of them, preferably the simplest one.thanks.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I don't know of any example where this was actually done. Do you have a reference ?

Comment: @my2cts I have found this very convincing https://phys.org/news/2011-01-which-way-detector-mystery-double-slit.html , and use it in my answers because it explains that it is the change in the wavefunctions introduced by any detection method that destroys the coherence. The answer here https://www.quora.com/How-do-the-detectors-work-in-the-double-slit-experiment-not-what-are-the-detectors-doing-but-how talks of using polarization filters .

Comment: @annav Interesting indeed, but not wholly surprising. Is a detection method possible that does not cause decoherence?

Comment: @my2cts I do not know. . I would think not with two slits as the experiment is carried out. Maybe with an analogue where only laser light  and weak measurement techniques are used. found this https://www.laserfocusworld.com/test-measurement/research/article/16562454/team-applies-weakmeasurement-principles-to-twoslit-interferometer-experiment

Comment: @Pranav [This](https://youtu.be/iyN27R7UDnI) video might help you. Answer is at 4:16.

Comment: @AnnaV That reference looks very promising. The paywall is no problem. Would David Bohm be right after all?

Comment: @my2cts I do not think so,  as bohmian mechanics is an interpretation for non relativistic quantum mechanics. I expect the  results should be explained with simple QM also. Bohmian mechanics does not work for the relativistic cases, so it cannot be "right"

Comment: @AnnaV so you disagree with the article that you refer to: "Our measured trajectories are consistent, as Wiseman had predicted, with the realistic but unconventional interpretation of mechanics of such influential thinkers as David Bohm and Louis de Broglie,"

Comment: @my2cts  I am saying that it is inevitable if the data are consistent with Bohmian mechanics they will be consisitent with a quantum mechanical model. Bohmian mechanics can be shown to give the same probabilistic results as quantum mechanics, that is why it is an interpretation. I would have to spend a lot of time to see how this can be done, but mathematics is mathmatics, and it should come out. note the date Jun 5th, 2011 . I just gave it as an example of weak measurements.